# Should my Name on Passport application include "4th"?

Tags: passports

On my birth certificate It shows my first middle and last name plus the suffix 4th.

(Frank Charles Beckert, 4th)

Do I need to put 4th on my passport next to my last name?

Comment: what country's passport are you applying for?

Comment: is that part of your name? if yes, of which part of your name? is it common in your country of citizenship?

Comment: What does Frank Charles Beckert, 3rd have in their passport?

Comment: Relevant from ELL SE: [“Senior” and “Junior” suffixes on ID cards and passports](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143895/senior-and-junior-suffixes-on-id-cards-and-passports)

Comment: Traditionally the "4th" part (or similar) isn't considered part of the name, but that tradition has been weakening over the last several decades.  When you list yourself last name first do you use the traditional "Beckert, Frank 4th" or the increasingly common "Beckert 4th, Frank"?  What's on your other IDs?

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to put 4th on my passport next to my last name?

You do not need to.  If you do, they will change it to *IV* (see letter (d) below).

To be clear, this means that you can either include the suffix *IV* in your passport or have no suffix at all, as you prefer.  You cannot have a suffix of *4th*.

> On my birth certificate It shows my first middle and last name plus the suffix 4th.
>
> (Frank Charles Beckert, 4th)

If you decide you don't want the suffix in your passport, you should say so explicitly on your application (see (a)(1) below) and, to be on the safe side, omit it from your signature (see (a)(2) below).

From the Department of State's [Foreign Affairs Manual](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM040301.html):

> 8 FAM 403.1-5(B)  Name Suffixes
>
> (CT:CITZ-64;   11-08-2021)
>
> a. Name suffixes (Jr., Sr., II, III, etc.) may be added or dropped based on the applicant's preference on form DS-11, regardless of whether they appear on the applicant's evidence of citizenship/nationality or ID.  You must determine how the applicant wishes their name to appear:
>
> (1)  If the name suffix appears on the evidence of citizenship/nationality or ID, you may assume that the applicant wants it included as part of their name unless the applicant requests otherwise.
>
> NOTE:  Adding or dropping a name suffix may change the Multiple Issuance Verification return (see 8 FAM 1102.1).
>
> (2)  If the applicant writes the suffix on the application, either in a name block (except for the other names in block nine) or in the applicant's signature, it should be included as a name.
>
> b. Name suffixes may be listed based on the applicant's preference, because naming conventions do not require strict logical adherence in the addition of a name suffix:
>
> (1)  An applicant may use a name suffix regardless of whether the applicant's parent/child uses the corresponding suffix;
>
> (2)  An applicant may use Sr. and Jr. interchangeably with I and II;
>
> (3)  Name suffixes may “skip” a generation, so the grandfather may be “John Smith I” and the grandson “John Smith II;” and
>
> (4)  An applicant may change their name suffix when an older generation dies, or when a new generation is born.
>
> c.  You must circle the name suffix on the application:
>
> [Image: Name suffix circled in block one.]
>
> d. Arabic ordinal numbers must be changed to Roman numerals, for example, 2nd to II, 3rd to III:
>
> [Image: Name suffix changed from ordinal to Roman numeral in block one.]
>
> e. Some applicants may include the prefix “Sr.” as an abbreviation for “Señor” in Spanish meaning “Mr.” or “Mister” in English.  If you determine that this is the case, follow the guidance in 8 FAM 403.1-5(C) regarding ranks and titles.
>
> f.  Name suffix issues are generally not sufficient cause to rewrite a passport, unless the Department disregarded the applicant's clear preference (see 8 FAM 1001.2).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reviewing your overall name picture. What name is listed on each of your IDs? What name is listed on your bank and brokerage accounts. If you own real estate, what name is listed on each deed and mortgage? Life insurance policies (where you own the policy, or are the beneficiary)? Car titles?

Once you see the overall picture, you might see a way forward to make them all consistent. If you are not happy with what you see, you may want to consult a lawyer who deals with estate planning.

Comment: estate planning? This is not a travel oriented answer at all and suggests not only a lack of reading the question, but a lack of knowing what site the question is on

Comment: Perhaps the question was asked on the wrong site. But passports last a long time and are used for much more than travel. Some people obtain passports only for domestic ID and never travel internationally.